# is there a way to get a global variable to a view in asp.net/razor to use it to test in and if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

right now I am trying to only show a view in my project if my global var privacy is set to true. I am not sure how to call my global variable the same way I do in my controllers but is there a way that I am not thinking of? right now I am trying to call a function that tests this variable and outputs true or false so I can use it in an if statement this feels like a lot more work and I am having problems trying it this way so if there is any way else please let me know.

```
 @if (Elearn.Controllers.AccountController.CheckGdpr())
    {
        <div class="popup">
            <div id="consent-popup" class="hidden">
                <p>
                    we advise our users to accept cookies for the best experience
                    <input class="btn-glow primary login" value="@_stringLocalizer["Accept Cookies"]" id="accept" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

controller function

```
public bool CheckGdpr()
    {
        string str = _configuration["privacy:GDPR"];
        string checkbol = "True";
        if (checkbol == str)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If someone knows how to correctly call a controller function too that would help a lot. I am getting an error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AccountController.CheckGdpr()'   Elearn  C:\Users\Isaac\source\repos\elearn2-final_sapce_fixes\Elearn\Elearn\Views\Account\LogOn.cshtml  74  Active

Comment: How about keeping user related info in Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if (Configuration.GetSection("privacy")["GDPR"] == "True")
```

this works